# goodFeaturesToTrack gives zero size vector

Tags: opencv, stl

I am trying to use the `goodFeatureToTrack()` function with opencv 2.4.3 on an gray image of lena...however I always get a zero size of the vector storing the features as `cv::Point2f`...I have tried using a zero mask also but in that case the application hangs up..I tried playing with the quality level value from 0.01 to 0.001. However still the size of the vector is zero..any idea?...following is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat frameROI;
    frameROI = imread("C:\\lena.jpg");
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
    cvtColor(frameROI,frameROI,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //Mat mask(frameROI.size(), CV_8UC1);
    //mask.setTo(Scalar::all(0));

    //goodFeaturesToTrack(frameROI,corners,10,0.001,10,mask,3,false,0.04);
    goodFeaturesToTrack(frameROI,corners,10,0.001,10);//AFTER EDIT
    cout<<"SIZE OF FEATURE VECTOR = "<<corners.size()<<endl;

    imshow("VIDEO ROI",frameROI);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
SIZE OF FEATURE VECTOR = 0
```

**EDIT:** afte Bob's suggestion I omitted the line for mask and modified the function..but now the application hangs up after the goodFeaturesToTrack function is invoked...Any idea?

Comment: Does the same happen if you set the mask to all 1's?

Comment: Yaaa....same is happening with all 1's...I have gone crazy with it now...is something wrong with my opencv 2.4.3? I am using the prebuild libraries that come with the downloaded version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem just now....instead of using the pre build libs n dlls....build it with MSVC2008 and now its working fine...the same points indicated by Bob are detected..

Answer (score 2):

By setting the mask to all zeros, you are basically excluding the whole image from the search. You should either remove `mask.setTo(Scalar::all(0));` completely (thus leaving the matrix empty) or replace it with `mask.setTo(Scalar::all(1));` (that is, to search for features in the whole image; otherwise, you should set the mask with 1's in the region of interest and 0's otherwise).

Following image is what your code returns for me if I remove `mask.setTo(Scalar::all(0));` completely and draw the points:

[image]